# Injecting ng-click into dynamic html

Tags: angularjs

I've got a scenario where I need to perform some regex matching and then when a match is found replace the text with a link, and then... the link should then execute a function:

```
app.factory('documentManipulationService',
    function ($sce) {
        return {
            Link: function (htmlDoc, termsToLink) {
                    termsToLink.sort(function (a, b) {
                        return b.length - a.length;
                    });
                    var regex = new RegExp('(?!")(' + termsToLink.join('|') + ')(?!")', 'g');

                    return $sce.trustAsHtml(htmlDoc.toString().replace(regex, '<span id="l$&" ng-click="previewLink()" class="packagerLink pointer">$&</span>'));
            }
        }
    });
```

The html is modeled by $scope.htmlDoc and is returned via an Api call and then modified by the above service like so:

```
$scope.htmlDoc = $sce.trustAsHtml(documentManipulationService.Link($scope.htmlDoc, [searchTerm]));
```

However, it doesn't look like the ng-click is making it in there.  I did some research and I think I need to compile it? But I've had no luck in doing so.

I'm not very familiar with directives and the ones I found online don't seem to work with my implementation as I require both ng-model and the froala directive (a text editor) on my implementation:

```
<textarea style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;"  
id="htmlEditor" froala="froalaOptions" ng-model="htmlDoc"></textarea>
```

How do I get the ng-click to show up in my modified html and have it fire off it's function?

Comment: Are you expecting the event to work inside the editor? Also `Link` is not right...javascript is case sensitive

Comment: @charliefl Yes for the editor, Link is my function inside a service, not a directive link.

Comment: ooops..my bad about link....was thinking directives. I doubt the editor is configured to compile angular inside it

Comment: @charliefl Np I figured that was it and no it's not configurable to do that from what I saw in the docs. What would make sense to me is watching the ng-model and compiling it when it changed, but no luck.

Comment: Does no good because the interface between model and editor will be html string. Editor creates it's own contenteditable and binds the string back to the textarea value

Comment: @charlietfl That's all above my head, I think Angular needs to know about the ng-click not the editor (the editor won't operate on the links per user training), I'm using these bindings: https://github.com/froala/angular-froala .  Looking like a bounty candidate of a question though.

Comment: To clarify the users should be able to click on the links and get a preview (the function firing), but they won't be editing them with the texteditor say using the anchor button in froala.